# How do I import SDK between SDK 8 and 9 in FCM firebase-messaging-sw.js service worker?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

The Firebase docs provide several ways to import SDK in service worker, which confused me. Here are the methods I discovered in the documentation:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#web-version-9

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
```

I can't utilize the method since I can't process my service worker because my project still uses webpack version 1. So I'm going to concentrate on the 'importScripts' techniques I discovered.

2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#web-version-8

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

This is a working approach that I've tested; nevertheless, I have some questions about it:

1. Is it okay to use this gstatic domain in production?
2. This official SDK differs from the quickstart-js that they gave.

---

3. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');
```

This is from the official example quickstart-js, however I still have a lot of questions about it:

1. It appears that they automatically updated the sample SDK, but the current version of Firebase is 9.6.1, not 9.2.0; should I remain with 9.2.0?
2. This approach only works in projects hosted by Firebase, and I can't find the init.js file matching to gstatic at the third line; is there a way to directly access that file?

---

Which approach should I utilize?

And I'm currently using Firebase 9.6.1 outside of my service worker; would utilizing Version 8 within my service worker cause any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'll stick to this:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but since I found the post, others may as well. Using the compat version of the importScripts was absolutely the correct choice at that time. One of the issues you would have been up against, was support for es6 in some browsers.

**(As of 2023)**
Service workers (ES6) are supported by many browsers now, including Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. The only browsers that I know that do not, are Internet Explorer and the iOS version of Safari.

You can still use ES6 service workers with browsers that don't support it, but you'll need to have a transpiler if you want them to be able to view your page. Otherwise, an error will likely be shown. The code is different, so their browser won't be able to read it. A transpiler basically reverts the code to a standard that can be read.

To use a ES6 service workers, you will have to update the way you register it. For example, I am creating a Flutter Web app, so I register my service worker in my index.html file:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js', { type: 'module' });
```

The only difference is the second parameter, where I set the type to module.

When that's added, you'll be able to also use the ES6 imports in your service worker:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

Again, to reiterate - you'll want to understand transpiling before using ES6. Currently, the iOS version of Safari uses some ES6 features, but not all of them (including service workers).

Comment: Just one last comment - to find the latest firebasejs files, you can go visit this link: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases